# Running commands in parallel with a limit of simultaneous number of commands

Tags: linux, bash, parallel-processing

Sequential: `for i in {1..1000}; do do_something $i; done` - too slow

Parallel: `for i in {1..1000}; do do_something $i& done` - too much load

How to run commands in parallel, but not more than, for example, 20 instances per moment?

Now usually using hack like `for i in {1..1000}; do do_something $i& sleep 5; done`, but this is not a good solution.

**Update 2**:
Converted the accepted answer into a script: http://vi-server.org/vi/parallel

```
#!/bin/bash

NUM=$1; shift

if [ -z "$NUM" ]; then
    echo "Usage: parallel <number_of_tasks> command"
    echo "    Sets environment variable i from 1 to number_of_tasks"
    echo "    Defaults to 20 processes at a time, use like \"MAKEOPTS='-j5' parallel ...\" to override."
    echo "Example: parallel 100 'echo \$i; sleep \`echo \$RANDOM/6553 | bc -l\`'"
    exit 1
fi

export CMD="$@";

true ${MAKEOPTS:="-j20"}

cat << EOF | make -f - -s $MAKEOPTS
PHONY=jobs
jobs=\$(shell echo {1..$NUM})

all: \${jobs}

\${jobs}:
        i=\$@ sh -c "\$\$CMD"
EOF
```

Note that you must replace 8 spaces with 2 tabs before "i=" to make it work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[GNU Parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) is made for this.

```
seq 1 1000 | parallel -j20 do_something
```

It can even run jobs on remote computers. Here's an example for re-encoding an MP3 to OGG using server2 and local computer running 1 job per CPU core:

```
parallel --trc {.}.ogg -j+0 -S server2,: \
     'mpg321 -w - {} | oggenc -q0 - -o {.}.ogg' ::: *.mp3
```

Watch an intro video to GNU Parallel here:

> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OpaiGYxkSuQ

Comment: Haven't know about "moreutils" and that there's already a tool for the job. Looking and comparing.

Comment: The `parallel` in moreutils is not GNU Parallel and is quite limited in its options. The command above will not run with the parallel from moreutils.

Comment: One more option: `xargs --max-procs=20`.

Answer (score 4):

Not a bash solution, but you should use a Makefile, possibly with `-l` to not
exceed some maximum load.

```
NJOBS=1000

.PHONY = jobs
jobs = $(shell echo {1..$(NJOBS)})

all: $(jobs)

$(jobs):
    do_something $@
```

Then to start 20 jobs at a time do

```
$ make -j20
```

or to start as many jobs as possible without exceeding a load of 5

```
$ make -j -l5
```

Comment: Looks like the non-hacky solution for now.

Comment: `echo -e 'PHONY=jobs\njobs=$(shell echo {1..100000})\n\nall: ${jobs}\n\n${jobs}:\n\t\techo $@; sleep \`echo $$RANDOM/6553 | bc -l\`' | make -f - -j20` Now it looks more hacky again.

Comment: @vi: oh my ....

Comment: Converted your solution to a script. Now it can be used with ease.

Answer (score 2):

One simple idea:

Check for i modulo 20 and execute the wait shell-command before do_something.

Comment: It will either wait for all current tasks to complete (creating sags in the number of tasks plot) or wait for one specific task that can stall for longer time (again creating sags in this case)

Comment: @Vi: Shell wait is for all background tasks that belong to this shell.

Answer (score 2):

<sub><sup>posting the script in the question with formatting:</sup></sub>

```
#!/bin/bash

NUM=$1; shift

if [ -z "$NUM" ]; then
    echo "Usage: parallel <number_of_tasks> command"
    echo "    Sets environment variable i from 1 to number_of_tasks"
    echo "    Defaults to 20 processes at a time, use like \"MAKEOPTS='-j5' parallel ...\" to override."
    echo "Example: parallel 100 'echo \$i; sleep \`echo \$RANDOM/6553 | bc -l\`'"
    exit 1
fi

export CMD="$@";

true ${MAKEOPTS:="-j20"}

cat << EOF | make -f - -s $MAKEOPTS
PHONY=jobs
jobs=\$(shell echo {1..$NUM})

all: \${jobs}

\${jobs}:
        i=\$@ sh -c "\$\$CMD"
EOF
```

Note that you must replace 8 spaces with 2 tabs before "i=".

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in {1..1000}; do 
     (echo $i ; sleep `expr $RANDOM % 5` ) &
     while [ `jobs | wc -l` -ge 20 ] ; do 
         sleep 1 
     done
done
```

Comment: May be `while [ \`jobs | wc -l\` -ge 20]; do`?

Comment: sure, but in my sample, I'd then have to compute `njobs` twice, and performance is quite important in shell scripts that run sleep tasks ;)

Comment: I mean your version doesn't work as expected . I change `sleep 1` to `sleep 0.1` and it start to average njobs to 40-50 instead of 20.

If there are more than 20 jobs we need to wait for any job gets finished, not just wait 1 second.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ps` to count how many processes you have running, and whenever this drops below a certain threshold you start another process.

Pseudo code:

```
i = 1
MAX_PROCESSES=20
NUM_TASKS=1000
do
  get num_processes using ps
  if num_processes < MAX_PROCESSES
    start process $i
    $i = $i + 1
  endif
  sleep 1 # add this to prevent thrashing with ps
until $i > NUM_TASKS
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this.

```
threads=20
tempfifo=$PMS_HOME/$$.fifo

trap "exec 1000>&-;exec 1000<&-;exit 0" 2
mkfifo $tempfifo
exec 1000<>$tempfifo
rm -rf $tempfifo

for ((i=1; i<=$threads; i++))
do
    echo >&1000
done

for ((j=1; j<=1000; j++))
do
    read -u1000
    {
        echo $j
        echo >&1000
    } &
done

wait
echo "done!!!!!!!!!!"
```

using named pipes, every time, it runs 20 sub shell in parallel.

Hope it help :)